# ошибка при подключении к базе данных. Не может использовать Open у MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, linux

Есть сервер на Linux, с прослушкой HTTP запросов, данные в виде JSON десериализуются и заносятся в БД, в ответ так же отправляется JSON. У пользователя все нормально, даже получает ответ, но на сервере возникает ошибка:

> Could not resolve type with token 01000fe from typeref (expected class 'System.Security.PermissionSet' in assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')

Когда запускаю на Windows, все нормально. Linux тоже имеет подключение к базе и может вызывать ее хранимые процедуры, все работает, данные обновляются.

Ошибка возникает при подключении к MySQL, когда использую `connection.Open()`. Долгое время пытался зарегистрировать MySql.Data.dll в GAC, но это не помогло.

Comment: `TypeLoadException` с указанием токена (вместо названия типа) обычно означает что версия библиотеки, подключенной во время выполнения приложения отличается от версии библиотеки, успользованной при сборке приложения. Либо вероятно, что библиотека из Linux сборки просто не поддерживает класс, который вы используете.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, есть два (как минимум) провайдера для MySql. / В .NET Core нет GAC. / Подключите nuget-пакет MySql.Data к вашему проекту и деплойте его со всеми остальными библиотеками.

Comment: @aepot у меня в сборке System.Security.Permission версии 4.7.0, а в сообщении об ошибке просит версию 4.0.3.0, как я понял. Есть ли решение, чтобы Linux начал работать с новой версией?

Comment: где вы увидели 4.7.0?

Comment: @aepot В свойствах System.Security.Permissions(4.7.0), в солюшене, в пакетах тоже написана версия 4.7.0

Comment: Так у вас .NET Framework 4.x чтоли? Почему у вас версия 4.7.0? Как вы ее подключали к проекту? Должна быть 5.0.0.

Comment: @aepot нет, 5.0, она идет в пакете MySql.Data(установлена последней версии). Я посмотрел, это не та версия, версия Security.Permission 4.0.3.0, как и указано в ошибке. Я попытался добавить этот атрибут, но выходит другая ошибка( 
`expected class 'System.Security.PermissionSet' in assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`
Такого класса я вообще не нашел

Comment: Если .NET 5, то версия NuGet пакета должна быть 5.0.x. Обновите. Если добавляли референс на библиотеку вручную, удалите этот референс и переустановите NuGet пакет System.Security.Permissions.

Comment: @aepot это пакет MySql.Data, там версия пакета 8.0.26, а версия dll system.security.permissions 4.7.0, это последняя версия, другие только ниже

Comment: MySql.Data в .NET 5 зависит от пакета  System.Security.Permissions (>= 4.7.0), то есть нужна минимальная версия 4.7.0, но можно установить актуальную 5.0.0. Прицепите эту библиотеку отдельным NuGet пакетом.